# Triple (or quadruple) boot MacOS Monterery, Windows (Bootcamp or otherwise), Ubuntu, Kali Linux, on mid 2015 macbook pro questions and problems w apfs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, boot-camp

I followed this tutorial about a year ago on MacOs Catalina Machine to install Bootcamp, then shrink the partition within Windows 10, then install Ubuntu: https://robpickering.com/triple-boot-macbook-pro-macos-windows-10-linux/

I have questions and problems and don't quite understand some fundamentals about the process.

The setup worked great but after sometime, and I'm assuming a MacOs update, only the Ubunutu and MacOs partitions would boot. Something stranged happened to the Windows install where it reverted back to the install Windows ten screen. It wouldn't let me pass the error: "Windows 10 requires a media driver" and when I browsed both the already installed system (which I verified was still intact) or used a freshly created usb from The Media Creation Tool, Windows 10 could not find any relevant drivers.

So, I tried a number of things but this left me with the only option which was to remove Bootcamp through MacOS which ended up destroying Ubuntu in the process and reallocating all the space back to MacOS. I wasn't sure if there would be some problems associated with that and I liked the idea of a clean Monterey install so I wiped the 1TB SSD with Parted Magic and reinstalled Monterey from a usb again.

I got it all working, following the same process but then adding on the Kali linux install in the free space following Ubuntu. It booted correctly on each partition once or twice until suddenly Windows 10 wouldn't boot and neither would Kali.  I was able to force boot into Windows 10 using Plop boot manager, but that must have corrupted something because on the next boot it said it needed a recovery windows media. I never got Kali to boot again.

Now I have started over again and have a freshly install Monterey and have not installed Bootcamp but the entire 1 TB SSD is formatted with APFS. Prior to installing Monterey, I tried to make two linux partition and leave a free space for windows using Gparted and also with Disk Utility under MacOS installer. Each time I could only see a way to have one large APFS volume because it wouldn't show the other partitions with any room leftover in Disk Utility. Gparted doesn't support APFS. I have done a little research on APFS and think I understand that what I had been using was One APFS volume that encompassed the other partitions and that it was unalterable under anything but the Bootcamp utility which would only remove it and everything in it.

One final misunderstanding that I don't quite get is that while MacOS is a UEFI based operating system, Bootcamp Windows 10 installs are actually inside the APFS container with an MBR.  Is that correct?  If so, how should I be installing the Linux installations? With a bios/mbr, or with UEFI?

Thanks and I realize I may have a number of questions here but what I'm really looking for is a confirmation that I am doing this a workable way, and if it's worth proceeding with. Also, is there any other way to avoid using bootcamp altogether that is stable?

The mid-2015 Macbook Pro has a gen 4 intel cpu and 16GB ram. I didn't think it would be good enough to virtualize windows on and I just wanted this to work for performance reasons.

Comment: My humble suggestion is to run those operating systems under a VM within MacOS.  There is very little hit to performance and the benefits outweigh the downfalls.  I know this isn't what you asked but I myself have found that all of the effort simply isn't worth it.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will keep it in mind.  Do you have a recommendation of open-source hypervisor?  I think I would still like to know the answers to some of the questions here so maybe someone else will offer a solution. I also have previously run Windows 10 in Parallels on the same machine a few years ago and I remember it being a major performance hit.  The other thing is that Kali Linux, which I'm just reading about, apparently benefits from a bare-metal install because some tools won't work correctly virtualized.

Comment: I myself use VirtualBox on Windows, MacOS, and Linux.  I can share the VMs between my platforms.  And certainly! :) I posted a COMMENT rather than an ANSWER for a reason.  I hope you get your answer.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas  Do you have an opinion on whether shrinking the MacOS APFS volume and then installing Ubuntu on its own Ext4 partition and then running Windows 10 and Kali in a VM from Ubuntu would be a better setup performance-wise or do you think that would also be a wasted effort? I'm thinking that Ubuntu may have a lighter footprint than MacOS Monterey.  Thanks.  I also just want to tinker with Linux a little more than a VM allows.

Comment: No, I don't have an opinion. ` I also just want to tinker with Linux a little more than a VM allows` .. what on earth do you mean?  What do you want to do that the VM won't?  This makes no sense to me.  Even the CPU gets passed through to the VM.

Answer (score -1):

As someone who has been obsessed with adding a fourth OS to my triple-booting 2012 MacBook Pro ever since the release of ChromiumOS, I can appreciate your struggles.  I have both helpful and possibly unhelpful info to share.  I can tell you it is possible to quad-boot MacOS, Win 10, Ubuntu 22.14 (or any Linux distro) and ChromeOS Flex on a MacBook Pro; however, only on the model released the year before yours, otherwise known as the 11,2.

How do I know?  I’ve got two of them right now and I can either boot into any one of those OS’s natively, or virtualise the others in MacOS all from those same partitions.  All that being said, I have zero actual knowledge of how bootloaders work, why they get boinked up, and/or the code behind fixing them; nonetheless, I can confidently say, with this set up, repairing the boot process is easy.

Now, I haven’t attempted two Linux distros, but you may not even need to bother updating grub with every UEFI coup.  So long as you run gdisk off of a live Ubuntu USB, and can rebless rEFInd, rEFInd should take care of the rest.  I say this because I’ve gotten whimsical with resizing the partitions (with unbacked-up data on them) and after backtracking through some terminal commands, previously unbootable Win 10 and Ubuntu are back in action.

I’m working on walkthroughs for setting up these quad-booting babies, but for now, here’s the guide I used primarily -> https://www.innoq.com/en/blog/triple-booting-a-mac/  Note: I never bothered with turning off SIP and a couple other things in there and it still worked.  But he doesn’t even get into installing the fourth OS, which is really just a matter of removing the SSD while installing ChromeOS to an SD card from a usb.  Again, the 11,2 is really the only MacBook Pro worth doing this on.

Essentially, it’s the “latest” MacBook Pro that has an Intel chip, no NVIDIA card, an SD slot, AND Is fully supported by Google.  If you get the 2.8gHz i7 model, it proves to be a VERY useable computer.  I threw OWC’s Aura X2 in there, but I haven’t seen that much of a boost over Apple’s built in SSD.  With refurbished 11,2’s still out there, I’d recommend going this route for another option.  Or, we could make a deal.  ;)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Kinda odd that you can answer a question, but not comment on it, until you have a reputation of 50.  My "answer" really was more of a comment, as I say from the beginning...but go ahead and dislike all you want.